# What's this "End of script output before headers"?

Tags: apache, perl, permissions, xampp, cgi

I am trying to make a simple test with PERL. I wrote input.html and put it in the hdocs folder and output.cgi in the cgi-bin. Both are in XAMPP folder, using a mac. This is using apache too.

HTML File

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
<form action="/cgi-bin/output.cgi" method="post">
Enter Fahrenheit: <input type="text" name="fahrenheit" /><br />
Enter Distance in Miles: <input type="text" name="distance" /><br />        
<input type="submit" value="Convert!" />
</form>
```

Here is the CGI file that's supposed to show when user presses "Convert"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";


#### read form data
my $fahrenheit = param('fahrenheit');
my $distance = param('distance');


#### do the math
my $celcius = ($fahrenheit * 18.8) + 32;
my $kilometers = $distance * 1.60934;

#### display results
print "<h2>Assignment 3</h2>";
print "Conversion: <br />";
printf "Celcius: \$%.2f <br />", $celcius;
printf "Kilometers: \$%.2f <br />", $kilometers;
```

This is the Error Log of Apache

```
 Marker - Oct 15, 2016, 5:56:38 PM
 [Sat Oct 15 17:56:41.765457 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 3086] [client ::1:50144] AH01215: (13)Permission denied: exec of '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/output.cgi' failed: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/output.cgi, referer: http://localhost/input.html
 [Sat Oct 15 17:56:41.765785 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 3086] [client ::1:50144] End of script output before headers: output.cgi, referer: http://localhost/input.html
```

And this is what the page looks like in localhost where output.cgi is supposed to be showing

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
End of script output before headers: output.cgi

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

Answer (score 5):

As the error log says, Apache doesn't have permission to execute your CGI file

Add execute permissions for everyone using `chmod a+x cgi-bin/output.cgi` and it should work for you

By the way, the conversion for temperature should be

```
$celcius = ( $fahrenheit - 32 ) / 1.8
```

#### Update

Your question is like asking, *"I put the key in my car and I'm still not in Leicester. What did I do wrongly?"*

You seem to be unable to specify the path to your `output.cgi` file from the command line. That isn't a problem: it's a deficiency. You must learn more about the shell that you are using

If you really can't do that then you're in *way* above your head, so you must stop and work through some tutorials

Looking at your error log, the output.cgi is at

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/output.cgi
```

so you can either

```
chmod a+x /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/output.cgi
```

or

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin
```

followed by

```
chmod a+x output.cgi
```

Comment: it says `chmod: /cgi-bin/output.cgi: No such file or directory` when I put `chmod a+x /cgi-bin/output.cgi` in the terminal

Comment: Well you have to add the rest of the path. Your `/cgi-bin` directory won't be a root directory. Alternatively you could `cd` to where your CGI file is and just `chmod a+x output.cgi`

Comment: @JohnyB12: Looking at your error log, the `output.cgi` is at `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/output.cgi`, so you can either `chmod a+x /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/output.cgi` or `cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin` followed by `chmod a+x output.cgi`

Comment: I would get this `chmod: Unable to change file mode on output.cgi: Operation not permitted` when I do both of those.

Comment: I did something differently and that solved it. I used a different IDE. I initially used Sublime but switched to TextWrangler. Thank you so much for the help @Borodin

Comment: @JohnyB12: "Solving the problem" without knowing what problem you resolved and how you resolved it is much worse than being unable to continue. If you're lucky, then there will be another problem that you don't understand very soon, and you will have to fix things properly. Otherwise something will arise in a few months' time that you can't explain and is a result of this "fix". It is vital that you are precise and thorough if you hope to be a useful programmer. Sublime Text and Text Wrangler shouldn't make the difference between working and non-working code. You are on the wrong track.

Comment: @JohnyB12: Until now you seemed to be asking sensible questions, so I tried to help you despite your two previous down votes. With this "resolution" it is clear that you are looking for a quick fix and not a proper answer, so you have another downvote from me. Please never ***ever*** write software by changing your code until it seems to work. You have lost my respect.

Comment: I wanted to reiterate what @Borodin said. Fixing programs by changing random things until they work is a terrible idea. To be a successful programmer, you need to be far more methodical and you need to understand **why** your fixes have worked.